Prove that exists $L_1 \in RE, L_2 \in coRE$ s.t $L_1 \cap L_2 \notin RE \cup coRE$
Prove that exists $L_1 \in RE, L_2 \in coRE$ s.t $L_1 \cap L_2 \notin RE \cup coRE$

So the only languages I know outside of $RE\cup coRE$ are:

$L_{\infty} = \{ \langle M\rangle | |L(M)|=\infty\}$
$EQ = \{ \langle M_1,M_2 \rangle |L(M_1)=L(M_2)\}$

Also I was thinking about using counting methods, knowing $|RE|=\aleph_0$ but I'm not sure how to continue.
I'd love some help.

The problem with trying to target the known languages is that $L_1\cap L_2$ must be $\Delta_2,$ but those aren't. Naively we'd expect that the result will hold for "most" such $L_1$ and $L_2$, provided that they aren't highly correlated with one another, e.g. if we take some arbitrary RE $L_1$ and $L_2=L_1^c$ this clearly fails. They also can't be computable. So I'd suggest starting from known non-computable RE and co-RE sets (i.e. halting-type sets and their complements) and seeing if there's anything that might work there.

Hint: Most properties about TMs are neither in RE nor in coRE. So take a property about TMs in RE and a property in coRE and intersect them, and there's a good chance the resultant property will be in neither.
Solution: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be distinct strings. Then $L_1 = \{\langle T\rangle \mid \text{TM $T$ accepts $\alpha$}\}$ and $L_2 = \{\langle T\rangle \mid \text{TM $T$ doesn't accept $\beta$}\}$ satisfy the requirements.
Proof: It's clear that $L_1 \in \mathsf{RE}$ since you can just run $\langle M\rangle$ on $\alpha$. Similarly, $\overline L_2 \in \mathsf{RE}$ since you can run $\langle M\rangle$ on $\beta$. It now remains to show that $L_1 \cap L_2 = \{\langle T\rangle \mid \text{TM $T$ accepts $\alpha$ but not $\beta$}\} \not\in \mathsf{RE} \cup \mathsf{coRE}$.
To show $L_1 \cap L_2 \not\in \mathsf{RE}$, we give a mapping reduction $\overline{A_\mathsf{TM}} \leq_\mathrm{m} L_1 \cap L_2$. The mapping $f$ is defined as $f(\langle T, w\rangle) = T$ where
$T$ = "On input $x$,

If $x \neq \beta$, then accept.
If $x = \beta$, run $M$ on $w$. If $M$ accepts, then accept."
Then $T$ accepts $\alpha$ but not $\beta$ iff $M$ doesn't accept $w$.

To show $L_1 \cap L_2 \not\in \mathsf{coRE}$, we give a mapping reduction $A_\mathsf{TM} \leq_\mathrm{m} L_1 \cap L_2$. The mapping $f'$ is defined as $f'(\langle T, w\rangle) = T'$ where
$T'$ = "On input $x$,

If $x \neq \alpha$, then reject.
If $x = \alpha$, run $M$ on $w$. If $M$ accepts, then accept."
Then $T$ accepts $\alpha$ but not $\beta$ iff $M$ accepts $w$.

